# From where I can download android kernel source code?

Tags: android, kernel

Hi i want to downloads android 4.0 kernel source code. And I want to change it according to my device.
From where i can downloads it? 
Please let me know the steps to do it.

Comment: http://source.android.com

Comment: -1; literally typing your title into Google will find it.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html, everything should be there. Even step-by-step instructions how to install the repository.

Good luck!